# How do I detect the current user's text direction preference in Java?

Tags: java, text, localization

I'm writing my own Java GUI component, which will extend [`javax.swing.JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and use its [`#paint(Graphics)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) method to paint text on itself with the [`java.awt.Graphics#drawString(String, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) method. I don't know whether the user's language uses RTL or LTR text, but I do want my text to be placed on the left or right side of the component when appropriate. **How do I get the direction of the text so that I know where to draw the String?**

This project targets Java 8.

Comment: Is this / should this be a user preference?  Shouldn't it depend on the language for the text you are trying to render?

Comment: @StephenC yes, it should. That said, all I know is whether they want the text to be normally aligned (e.g. Left in English), centered, justified, or flush to the opposite side (e.g. Right in English)

Comment: Ermm ... in conventional terminology, LTR versus RTL rendering is not about alignment.  It is about what order the characters are displayed; e.g. http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/.  For example, in arabic, the first character in a word is to the right of the second one.

Comment: Actually, LTR versus RTL conventionally refers to the direction of character rendering, not text alignment / filling.  See http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/ for example.  If you are actually asking about text alignment, you are using the wrong terminology ... and you won't get relevant answers.

Comment: @StephenC  correct. The language library and Graphics#drawString method will take care of character order for me; I just need to know where to place it on component. It'll be like CSS's `text-align: start;`

Comment: So ... if you don't want to know about character rendering, why did you just accept an answer which talks about character rendering?  And why don't you fix your question to ask what you REALLY want to find out about?

Comment: @StephenC perhaps choosing the word "render" was poor. I hope my edits better reflect my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `java.text.Bidi` provides methods to check if a text is completely left-to-right, right-to-left or mixed. The static method

```
Bidi.requiresBidi(char[] text, int start, int limit)
```

returns `true` for left-to-right and `false` for right-to-left or mixed content. If you can ensure that your content is not mixed the static method is sufficient. Otherwise you have to instantiate a Bidi object to retrieve detailed information about your text.

Comment: This does not answer either the question asked (how to find the user's Bidi preference ... if that makes any sense) or the one he meant to ask (how to find the user's preference for text alignment and filling).